# Семи пядей во лбу

Tags: фразеология

Фразеологизм "семи пядей во лбу" является адъективным или субстантивным? 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Не помню, чтобы была такая типология фразеологизмов, но рискну предположить, что адъективный фразеологизм  равен по значению прилагательному, а субстантивный - существительному. Он семи пядей во лбу - то есть умный, толковый. Значит - адъективного типа. 
Молодежь, недавно закончившая вузы, ау, добавляйте или исправляйте. Спорить,наверное, есть о чем - можно ведь заменить  и существительным, умник например. Но все равно основным значением остается значение признака.

Comment: >Не помню, чтобы была такая типология фразеологизмов  

Её никогда и не было. Я, собственно, об этом и писал... Почемуто модератор щзадвинул в коммент...
Ваше идея насчет использования по типу прилагательного вполне логична (тоже думал о таком), но возникает вопрос, а существуют ли тогда (по этой типологии) *субстантивные* фразеологизмы?! Я что-то не могу представить...

Comment: Субстантивные? Ну хотя бы - камень преткновения... Хотя вы правы- со значением признака или действия фразеологизмов гораздо больше.

Comment: Да хоть один придумайте... Просто без такого примера предлагаемая идея типологии - мертворожденная. Я вот с некоторым скрипом вспомнил "гусь лапчатый", что можно считать фразеологизмам и с некоторыми оговорками - используемым как существительное. Всё остальное, что вспомнил, - эпитеты, причем явно адъективные.

Comment: Читайте внимательно... Один назвала. Можно и еще - авгиевы конюшни, альфа и омега,три кита... Только давайте не будем начинать спор о том, что такое фразеологизм. Да я и не претендую ни на какое рождение типологии, Бог с Вами. Просто дала предположительный ответ.

Comment: Хорошо, Ларf, не буду сейчас спорить, но странныо как-то относит подобные *эпитеты* к субстативным... 
ЗЫ Я совсем не собирался вызывать у Вас подобной реакции. Если совсем кратко, так хотел с Вашей помощью проверить Ваше же предположение.

Comment: Почему ж не было? Была и есть  В зависимости от семантики, морфологических свойств и синтаксической функции фразеологизма в предложении принято различать следующие типы ФЕ: 
1) субстантивные (или именные),значение – предмет или лицо: кисейная барышня; 
2) адъективные,значение – признак предмета: семи пядей во лбу; 
3) глагольные(действие): заметать следы; ломать голову; 
4) адвербиальные: значение – признак признака: на скорую руку; тихой сапой; 
5) междометные: была не была!; как бы не так!;
6) модальные: как пить дать.

Comment: По-крайней мере, такая классификация выглядит разумной.

Comment: А можно показать, где она была? Я довольно тщательно смотрел в интернете - ничего похожего.

>По крайней мере такая классификация выглядит разумной  
  
Да я бы обеими руками, но междe разумностью и общепринятостью - пропасть.

Answer (score 0):

> Он семи пядей во лбу - то есть умный, толковый.

Чтобы не создавать новый вопрос, поинтересуюсь здесь. А почему так говорят "семи пядей во лбу" ? Что это дословно может значить? Высокий лоб?

Comment: >Чтобы не создавать новый вопрос, поинтересуюсь здесь. А почему так говорят "семи пядей во лбу" ? Что это дословно может значить? Высокий лоб?

Скорее широкий.))) Именно ширина (не высота) лба считалась признаком интеллекта.    
Я не разделяю идею, что речь могла идти о полном росте, а не о высоте-ширине лба. 

См. еще [здесь][1]. 

[1]: http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=14.37

Comment: >о высоте-ширине лба.

Спасибо, понятно.

А слово "узколобый" означает что-то вроде человека небольшого ума? Или ограниченного, так сказать узких взглядов?

Comment: >А слово "узколобый" означает что-то вроде человека небольшого ума? Или ограниченного, так сказать узких взглядов?  

Да в общем-то один от другого недалеко ушел. Я бы сказал, что "узколобость" - это характеристика человека прямолинейного, не способного мыслить творчески, не по накатанным схемам. Да еще обычно агрессивно настроенного ко всем, кто пытается его переубедить.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Nikolja, я преобразовал Ваш комментарий в ответ, поскольку не было другой возможности разделить ветки и продолжить разговор.
Надеюсь на понимание. 

Я подумал, а хорошо ли понятна разница между высоким=низким и широким-узким лбами? Первое - это характеристика того, насколько далеко надбровные дуги находятся от переносицы. Второе - расстояние от надбровных дуг до начала волосяного покрова. Или места, где он когда-то начинался. Можно иметь низкий, но тем не менее - широкий лоб. Неандерталец - тому пример.